# 'python-qgis' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

As per - https://root676.github.io/installation.html - I am trying to install QNEAT3 via the OSGeo4W shell using `python-qgis -m pip install matplotlib`, however I am getting the following error message:

`'python-qgis' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I have had look and can't seem to find any info on this error, does anyone know why I am getting this or how I can fix it? I am running QGIS 3.4.1

Comment: I think there should be a space between `python` and `-qgis`. Try `python -qgis -m pip install matplotlib`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that results in `Unknown option: -q`?

Comment: My mistake, no need for the space. The original command was correct as I ran it using QGIS 3.8.1. How did you load the shell?

Comment: Like this: Start - type OSGeo4W Shell - hit Enter

Comment: Could you try downloading the latest QGIS version and test it? Could be a version issue.

Comment: Will try that, thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the problem? If not, please inform me via a bugticket at the QNEAT3 repository so that I can fix problems with the matplotlib installation.

Comment: Hoping to get it upgraded shortly and will update when I know

Answer (score -1):

For the latest version of QGIS just type `pip install matplotlib`